# git checkout is keeping files from other branch while switching

Tags: git, git-bash

so I have a strange problem with `git` on Windows, I have 2 branches as follows:

```
* newRoundedCar
  3D-CAD-design
```

this is the content of the branch called `newRoundedCar`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 User 197121  0 May 14 02:37 'ESP32 code'/
-rw-r--r-- 1 User 197121 76 Jun 13 08:21  README.md
```

this is the content of the branch called `3D-CAD-design` before switching to it:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 User 197121  0 Jun 13 08:27 '3D car CAD design'/
-rw-r--r-- 1 User 197121 76 Jun 13 08:21  README.md
```

when I wrote the following command to switch from `newRoundedCar` to `3D-CAD-design`:

```
$ git checkout 3D-CAD-design
```

the content of `3D-CAD-design` after switching to it:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 User 197121  0 Jun 13 08:27 '3D car CAD design'/
drwxr-xr-x 1 User 197121  0 May 14 02:37 'ESP32 code'/
-rw-r--r-- 1 User 197121 76 Jun 13 08:21  README.md
```

so it seems it copied the folder called `ESP32 code` from `newRoundedCar` to `3D-CAD-design` but when I do the the reverse like switching from `3D-CAD-design` to `newRoundedCar` , no files are copied, instead the branch called `newRoundedCar` stands as it was before switching, so I don't know this strange behavior happens.

everything is committed to the branch, I ran the command :

```
git status
```

and this is the result :

```
User@DESKTOP-1C6TOMA MINGW64 /d/codes/PROJECTS/third year/second term/embedded systems/Carcotech (newRoundedCar)
git status
On branch newRoundedCar
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/newRoundedCar'.
```

Comment: Question: Has the file `ESP32 code` been _committed_ in the `newRoundedCar` branch _before_ you switched to the other branch?

Comment: `git` will not delete a directory from disk if there are untracked files within it. Check `ls -A '3D car CAD design'` to see if there are any  files there, and `git status '3D car CAD design'/` to confirm that no file shows up as "tracked and modified"

Comment: Note that `git checkout` is deprecated. Use `git switch` instead

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, yes the `ESP32 code` been committed in the `newRoundedCar` branch before switching to the other branch, I edited the question to confirm that all files have been commited

Comment: Two possible reasons why the directory was not deleted: (1) There are untracked files in the directory. (2) Some software is using the directory; then Git is unable to remove it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen and j6t , actually you are right, I have explored the contents of these directories and when switching from one branch to another, the directory has .vscode and .pio files which are supposed to be in .gitignore, so they are untracked files, so it's my bad.